# typescript type error on indexing property

Tags: typescript-typings

I am trying to use a 3rd party TypeScript library, and I need to be able to do an index signature access to the properties. The object 't' looks like a t:any in the lambda expression. So I was not able to figure out the Type [key: string]: number; expression.

But what has me puzzled is that this passes all the compile tests (when I hard-code as a string the property key) (but when I change it to a variable, a one line change it fails). **Yes, I am more comfortable with JavaScript than TypeScript**

```
   public async telemetryValue(objects: ObjectSet<AnyTelemetry>, statType: string, start: Timestamp, end: Timestamp):
        Promise<Double | null> {
        let value: Double | null
        const legalStatTypes = new Set(["median", "top", "bottom"])
        if (!legalStatTypes.has(statType)) {
            throw RangeError(`Invalid statistic type: ${statType}`)
        }
        value = await objects
            .filter(t => Filters.and(
                t.timeStamp.range().gte(start),
                t.timeStamp.range().lte(end)))
            .average(t => t["median"])
        return value!
    }
```

However, changing that to a string variable explodes:

```
   public async telemetryValue(objects: ObjectSet<AnyTelemetry>, statType: string, start: Timestamp, end: Timestamp):
        Promise<Double | null> {
        let value: Double | null
        const legalStatTypes = new Set(["median", "top", "bottom"])
        if (!legalStatTypes.has(statType)) {
            throw RangeError(`Invalid statistic type: ${statType}`)
        }
        value = await objects
            .filter(t => Filters.and(
                t.timeStamp.range().gte(start),
                t.timeStamp.range().lte(end)))
            .average(t => t[statType])
        return value!
    }
```

with the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AggregatablePropertiesForResult<AggregatableProperties, BucketValue>'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AggregatablePropertiesForResult<AggregatableProperties, BucketValue>'.
```